# wordpress downloading php file instead of viewing the webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I installed wordpress on my local machine (backtrack) for experimenting. After I got everything setup I moved it to an Ubuntu Server so that everybody can access those pages at work. I followed the same instructions, I moved the wordpress folder into /var/www but I created a new database with the same username, password and hostname.

The problem is whenever I access the webpage @ubuntu it tries to download the file, if access the page @backtrack it goes to the dashboard and everything is fine.

I did not have an .htaccess file on either machine sop I created one just to see if it will fix the problem but it did not.

Apache works fine because I can get to some folders I have setup by going to

```
"http://ubuntuserver/folder name"
```

and the logs shows no errors because it is delivering the webpage to the client just fine but the client is downloading it instead.

Any Ideas why this is happening??

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't installed the PHP module for Apache or enabled it to use PHP using AddType in the Apache config file.

Comment: it is not enabled on backtrack either, both apache2.conf look the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your WebServer ( Apache here, i suppose ) is not configured to use PHP module and/or is missing some PHP configuration options.
[See here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml) for some basic configuration tutorial.